# Copy Query from Access to Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, excel-formula, vba

I'm having some problems when I try to import a Query from Access to Excel.

Some days ago I programmed a code (with some help of Google haha) to import a Table from Access to Excel:

```
Sub importQuery(DBFullName As String, data_sht As Worksheet)

     Dim cn As Object, rs As Object

     Dim i As Integer

     Dim TargetRange As Range

     Dim rows As Long, cols As Long

     Dim dataEmpty As Boolean

     Dim lastColString As String



     data_sht.Activate   

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     Set TargetRange = data_sht.Range("A1")

     Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

     cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";" 'the Access file is .accdb


     Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

     rs.Open "SELECT * FROM C_Paso2_SM_Cuplas", cn, , , adCmdUnspecified

     cols = rs.Fields.Count

     rows = data_sht.Range("A" & data_sht.rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 

     ' Copy titles of the Access Query

     For i = 0 To (cols - 1)

         TargetRange.Offset(0, i).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name

     Next

     ' Copy data

     TargetRange.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
End Sub
```

That code works but when I do this:

```
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM C_Paso2_SM_Cuplas", cn, , , adCmdUnspecified
```

I'm importing another Query called C_Paso**1**_SM_Cuplas, from the same file. What can I do? Why am I importing C_Paso**1**_SM_Cuplas when I say C_Paso**2**_SM_Cuplas? Is there other possibility to import an Access Query to Excel?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. The query you posted having an issue with is the exact same one as the one in your code. What's the problem? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I'm trying to import C_Paso2_SM_Cuplas but the code imports C_Paso1_SM_Cuplas!! See the difference: I need Paso2 and it imports Paso1. When I import Tables instead of Queries it works fine

Comment: Are there any records in `C_Paso2_SM_Cuplas`?   Add `rs.Close`, `Set rs = Nothing`, `cn.Close`, and `Set cn = Nothing` before `End Sub`.

Comment: No, there is just one C_Paso2_SM_Cuplas. But the data pasted in data_sht is the one from C_Paso1_SM_Cuplas

Comment: Can your code show the headers of `C_Paso2_SM_Cuplas`?

Comment: The headers are normal things like "Cost", "Quantity" and things like that

Answer (score 0):

Try this DAO solution.

```
Sub ImportFromAccessToExcel()

    Dim db1 As Database
    Dim db2 As Database
    Dim recSet As Recordset
    Dim strConnect As String

    Set db1 = OpenDatabase("C:\Database1.mdb")
    strConnect = db1.QueryDefs("Query3").Connect _
    & "DSN=myDsn;USERNAME=myID;PWD=myPassword"

    Set db2 = OpenDatabase("", False, False, strConnect)
    db2.Close
    Set db2 = Nothing

    Set recSet = db1.OpenRecordset("Query3")

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=recSet, Destination:=Range("$A$4"))
        .Name = "Connection"
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    End With

    recSet.Close
    db1.Close
    Set recSet = Nothing
    Set db1 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I will be able to try it on Tuesday. But why do you need a password? It's an Access file. Will it work in a .accdb instead of a .mdb? Thanks

Comment: That's just an example.  If you don't need a password, just leave it out.  You can find all kinds of connection strings for Access using the link below.  
https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/